# Can python freeze be made to compile 32 bit binaries on a 64 bit linux

Tags: python, linux, 32bit-64bit, freeze

I've a number of python scripts that I am likely to need to distribute to users who may have minimal x86 linux setups and no guarantees of having python or a particular version of it.
My desktop is an x86-84 architecture setup, but I am able to cross compile 32 bit elf's with GCC.

The python freeze script is currently outputting a 64 bit elf, plus a 64 bit .so. Is there any option/hack etc known to get this to compile to a 32 bit output?

Answer (score 1):

Could you use something like`make CFLAGS="-m32"`.?

Comment: This is a start, but I've had problems. First you will find that it cannot find a glibc header, so you'll need to install libc6-dev-i386, but then it will be using python headers configured for the 64 bit system. I'm now trying to figure that one out.

Comment: That looks like the following:In file included from /usr/include/python2.6/Python.h:58,
                 from config.c:18:
/usr/include/python2.6/pyport.h:694: error: #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."